# Start new variable scope from smarty block function

Tags: scope, smarty3

I'm using a block function to load data without polluting the local scope:

```
<h1>{$title}</h1>

{loadstuff}
     <h2>{$title}</h2>
     <p>{$text}</p>
{/loadstuff}

<p>{$text}</p>
```

Is there a good way to start a new variable scope within a block function? In Smarty2, I used this hack:

```
function smarty_block_loadstuff($params, $content, $smarty, &$repeat) {
    static $replace_stack = array();

    if ($repeat) {
        $replace_stack []= $smarty->get_template_vars();
        $smarty->assign(loadstuff());
    } else {
        // Reload the original vars
        $template_vars = &$smarty->get_template_vars();
        $template_vars = array_pop($replace_stack);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

The reference replacement on $template_vars does not work for Smarty3. Smarty3 changed a lot regarding scoping and I hoped it might be possible to just start a nested scope. Unfortunately, I found no way of adding a scope within the API. Now I'm doing this hack:

```
$smarty->clearAllAssign();
$smarty->assign('smarty', $smarty); // It seems to be necessary
$smarty->assign(array_pop($replace_stack));
```

Which is really ugly. Do you know of any way I could improve on this?

Comment: I found that the hack used above does not work well, because it clears variables assigned in the template. Instead, I'm doing this:

    `$replace_stack []= $smarty->tpl_vars`

and later

    `$smarty->tpl_vars = array_pop($replace_stack);`

which is still very hacky but works properly so far.

Answer (score 0):

here is what we can to do to get getTemplateVars() working like in samrty2,

"file: smarty_internal_templatebase.php" , 
section "

```
 if ($merge_tpl_vars){} ,
```

here we can merge variables assigned when template parsed,

```
$_template->tpl_vars = $save_tpl_vars
```

can be changed to:

```
$this->tpl_vars = array_merge($this->tpl_vars, $save_tpl_vars, $_template->tpl_vars);
```

now smarty3 getTemplateVars() returns variables assigned in template, like smarty2

Comment: Thinks for the comment, but I wouldn't want to patch Smarty for this. I found that replacing the $smarty->tpl_vars as indicated in my comment to work well in practice.